# Can I run more than two VMs on Windows Server 2012 Standard if guest OSes are not WS2012?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, licensing, windows-server-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

It is said [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012#cite_note-long-44) that Windows Server 2012 Standard allows you to install it on one 2-processor machine *and* run up to two VMs of itself.

But what's about other guest OSes? Can't find anything about that.

Comment: What did Microsoft say when you asked them?

Comment: Short answer is yes.  There were a few articles about the fact that if you're not virtualising Windows Servers, the new 2012 standard license can be very cost effective, e.g. http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/gabeknuth/archive/2012/07/19/Microsoft_2700_s-mixed-message-on-Windows-Server-2012-licensing_3A00_-What_2700_s-the-real-story_3F00_.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a MS-licensing policy about w2k12 I would say this is not about anything else but the needed number of licences for it. So for other OSes you need a licence for that OS to run it as VM.

Comment: So, I can run hundreds of linux VMs with one 2012 server?

Comment: @Gman I would say yes. But can you post the exact EULA-text or provide a link to it?